# Instagram GET /users/user-id Not returning any data?

Tags: php, api, json, instagram, endpoints

I'm trying to display the number of followers my account has in my php page and for some reason when I try to use the https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/follows?access_token={$accessToken} fetchData line, I get no information.

```
<?php    

    $userinfo = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/follows?access_token={$accessToken}");
    $userinfo = json_decode($userinfo);


    foreach($userinfo->data as $profile) {
        $followers = $profile->counts->follow_by;
        echo "Followed by: ".$followers;
    }
?>
```

But if I use the same code with a different endpoint command and call different data, it works great (like below)

```
<?php    

    $userinfo = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token={$accessToken}");
    $userinfo = json_decode($userinfo);


    foreach($userinfo->data as $profile) {
        $followers = $profile->likes->count;
        echo "Followed by: ".$followers;
    }
?>
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `users/{userid}/follows` endpoint will not return any data on your profile. It only returns an array of user profiles that *you follow*.

The quickest way way to access your followers count is to use the `users/{userid}` endpoint:

```
$userinfo = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/YOUR_USER_ID?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN");
$userinfo = json_decode($userinfo);

$followers = $userinfo['data']['counts']['followed_by'];

echo "Folled by: " . $followers . " people";
```

Also, for future reference, I highly recommend you test your calls using [Instagram's API Console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/). That way you can see what data is being returned from each call, so that you can access it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think the link I really needed was `$followers = $userinfo['data']['counts']['followed_by'];`. I changed that and then added the "true" input and it all worked! Thanks `$userinfo = json_decode($userinfo);`

Comment: I am trying to get the array of users, but for some reason it returns no data just: ```{"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}```. Any ideas on how to get the array of users that follow me?

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old Question but it may help some one else.

```
$api_key = 'YOR_API_KEY';
$user_id = 'XXX';
$data = @file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$user_id/?client_id=$api_key");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
echo $data['data']['counts']['followed_by'];
//echo '<pre/>';
//print_r($data);
```

This do not required access token its only required API key. If you are not able to get the user id of the user but you know his/her name just go to the page and simply inspect profile image in browser you will figure out the user id from there.

I hope it will help some one else.